# Peewee. How generate on conflict on constrain for specified column?

Tags: postgresql, peewee

I use peewee with postgresql. I try generate query for many entries insertion with resolving insertion conflict for specified column.

models.py

```
from peewee import *

from datetime import date

from db_init import db


class User(Model):
    username = CharField(constraints=[SQL('CONSTRAINT unique_username UNIQUE')], 
                         max_length=100, unique=True)
    date_create = DateField(default=date.today)

    class Meta:
        table_name = '_users'
        database = db
```

I run this code

```
usernames = [f'username{i}' for i in range(5)]
data = [{'username': username} for username in usernames]
q = User.insert_many(data, fields=[User.username])
q2 = q.on_conflict(action='IGNORE', conflict_target=[User.username])
```

and expect that generate

```
INSERT INTO "_users" ("username", "date_create") VALUES ('username0', '2021-06-01'), ('username1', '2021-06-01'), ('username2', '2021-06-01'), ('username3', '2021-06-01'), ('username4', '2021-06-01') ON CONFLICT ("username") DO NOTHING RETURNING "_users"."id"
```

but peewee generate query without specific column in ON CONFLICT statement

```
INSERT INTO "_users" ("username", "date_create") VALUES ('username0', '2021-06-01'), ('username1', '2021-06-01'), ('username2', '2021-06-01'), ('username3', '2021-06-01'), ('username4', '2021-06-01') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING "_users"."id"
```

Please, explain what i do wrong?

Comment: This is fixed in Peewee https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/commit/9794176d6a9fbf041273789d0808ba9dc88c09c5 - previously Peewee did not support conflict target when action was DO NOTHING/IGNORE. This patch allows conflict target to be specified.

Comment: @coleifer, thank you for informing. I also discovered this when I independently researched the source code of the previous version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in Peewee [github.com/coleifer/peewee/commit/…](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/commit/9794176d6a9fbf041273789d0808ba9dc88c09c5) - previously Peewee did not support conflict target when action was DO NOTHING/IGNORE. This patch allows conflict target to be specified